# How to develop extension Mozilla Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I would like to develop an extension for the Mozilla browser anymore I don't know anything about how to get started, I searched internet tutorials but I don't think what I would like to develop,I would like to develop a simple extension that alerts users when they access specific sites something similar as the page action extensions Google Chrome, please how can I develop this extension could anyone help me?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons

Comment: Example of basic restartless addon: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9025999/forks and here: https://github.com/Noitidart/l10n